# Display content on web page depending on Google Analytics data

Tags: cookies, web, google-analytics

Is it possible to use data from Google Analytics when someone visits my web page?

I would like to get information about the visitor, eg:

- location
- how many times he visited the page
- from where he comes
- time spent on website
- etc

And depending on those informations display proper content. Or even add them (silently) to the contact form.

Is it possible to use the data collected by Google Analytics or should I create my own mechanism based on cookies? Maybe any other solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't possible.  Universal Analytics uses a cookie with an ID for the user and handles the rest on the server, so there's no data available to you.  However, all of the info that Google is tracking is accessible to you.

location you can get via the users IP

visits you can get by setting a cookie on each user and tracking sessions

referrer should be in the request headers

time spent can be tracked the same way that ga does, but keeping track of the time everytime the user creates another hit